# Locationヘッダを出力してもリダイレクトされない

Tags: php

以下のコードでPHPのログイン処理を実装したのですが、コメントの`//ログイン成功`までは動いているのですが、その後の`function login()`でheader()を使ってページ遷移を実装しているのですが、ページ遷移せずに、真っ白なページのままです。
urlは`http://sandbox.localhost/basic_login.php`のままになっています。どこが間違っているかわかりますか?

**Basic_login.php**

```html
<?php
require('common.php');
require('functions.php');

$pdo = connectDB();

session_start();
$_SESSION['id']=0;
$_SESSION['mail_address']="";
$_SESSION['login']=0;

$error="";
$mail_address = "";
$password = "";

switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'POST':
        if(isset($_POST["login"])){
            $mail_address = htmlspecialchars($_POST["mail_address"], ENT_QUOTES);
            $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"], ENT_QUOTES);
            if(strlen($mail_address)==0)
                $error = "メールアドレスが入力されていません。";
            if(strlen($password)==0)
                $error = "パスワードが入力されていません。";
            if(strlen($error)==0){
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
                $st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE mail_address=:mail_address");
                $st->bindParam(':mail_address', $mail_address);
                $st->execute();
                if($st->rowCount()>0){
                    $row = $st->fetch();
                    if($row['password']==$password){
                        //ログイン成功!
                        login($row);
                    }else{
                        $error ="メールアドレスまたはパスワードが違います。";
                    }
                }else{
                    $error = "メールアドレスまたはパスワードが違います。";
                }
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])){
            $cookie = $_COOKIE['cookie'];
            $mail_address = $cookie['mail_address'];
            $password = $cookie['password'];
        }
        break;
}

function login($user){
    $_SESSION["id"]=$user["id"];
    $_SESSION["mail_address"]=$user["mail_address"];
    $_SESSION["login"]=1;

    $checkboxValue = $_POST['remember'];
    if($checkboxValue){
        setcookie("cookie[mail_address]", $user["mail_address"]);
        setcookie("cookie[password]", $user["password"]);
    }else{
        if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie[mail_address]']))
            setcookie('cookie[mail_address]', time() -1800);
        if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie[password]']))
            setcookie('cookie[password]', time() - 1800);
    }

    header("Location : http://sandbox.localhost/edit_profile.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>ログイン</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bower_components/bootswatch/paper/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basic_signin.css">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="basic_login.php">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">ログイン</h2>
            <?php
            if(strlen($error)>0){
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' > エラー : {$error}</div>";
            }
            ?>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="sr-only">メールアドレス</label>
            <input type="email"  name="mail_address" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofucus value="<?php echo $mail_address ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="sr-only" >パスワード</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="foem-control" placeholder="Password" required  value="<?php echo $password ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" name="remember">Remember me
              </label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="ログイン">
          </form>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" id="signin" onclick="toSignin()">サインイン</button>
        </div>

      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/basic_login.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locationヘッダーの記述に誤りがあります。
header("Location: xxxxx")のところで、Locationの後ろのスペースを削除してください。

参考サイト
http://blog.s-giken.net/98.html

Comment: おお!!  できました!ありがとう御座います。